# работа Log.i вне MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, логирование

Использьую в проекте логирование: `Log.i("INF", "сообщение...")`, и если в MainActiviry всё ок, то когда пытаюсь вставить в данный код (RoomAdapter):

```
Отрывок из RoomAdapter

public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RoomViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {
        holder.menuTitle.setText(rooms.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.menuItem.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(rooms.get(position).getColor()));
        holder.threeDots.setTag(position);
        Log.i("INF", "pos" + position);
...
```

логирование не срабатывает, подскажите, из-за чего это может быть?

P.S. Код выполняется, но логов нет.

Comment: Вы в какой версии AS работаете? Может быть установлен фильтр по пакету или типу сообщения.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка оказалась банальной:

Перед каждым запуском мне нужно было отчищать данные приложения, я думал что после отчистки, приложение перезапускается автоматически (в logcat было подключение у процессу), чего не проимходило.